# Entity Framework (6.1.3) updates not reflected in the DataContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, datacontext

1)  I add a new entity to the context and call `_context.SaveChanges()`.  Entity is added as expected

2)  I update the same entity and call `_context.SaveChanges()` I put a break point immediately after and inspect the _context and my update is reflected on the entity AND is indeed saved to the DB.

3)  I call `_context.Set< T >().ToList()` later in my code base and the update is NOT reflected on the entity.  (`_context` does not reflect the updated value at this point)

What could possibly be the cause and what can I do to resolve?  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Responding to request for code..

From the repository...

```
    public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<T>().ToList();
    }

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        _context.SaveChanges();

       var xxx = _context.Customers.ToList();
    }
```

From the call to get all...

```
    var customersToUpdate = _customerManager.GetAllCustomers();
```

From the CustomerManager...

```
    public List<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        return _customerRepository.GetAll();
    }
```

Pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code parts?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you use only one instance of the _customerRepository? And that every time you update the _context you do it in the same context under _customerRepository ? It sounds like you have multiple instance, one get updated while the others dont

Comment: I thought that too. But I don't.  Unless ninject is doing something funky that I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to tell EF that you updated something. 
Easiest way of doing that is:

```
var customer = _context.Customers.First();

customer.Name = "new name";

_context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified; 

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Or you can be more specific of what is changed like below:

```
customer.Name = "new name";
context.Entry(customer).Property(u => u.Name).IsModified = true;
_context.SaveChanges();
```

You can enable [automatic changes detection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205) like that:

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

In this case

- DbSet.Find
- DbSet.Local
- DbSet.Remove
- DbSet.Add
- DbSet.Attach
- DbContext.SaveChanges
- DbContext.GetValidationErrors
- DbContext.Entry
- DbChangeTracker.Entries

all will automatically detect changes.